# Random color for each mesh

Tags: python

I would need to export a 3DS-file where each mesh has an unique color and to do this I guess I have to crate a material with an unique color for each selected mesh and wonder how to do this. preferable I would like to avoid to create unused material. One other option would be to edit the 3DS-file but I think that is much harder. This is what I have tried with limited success.

```py
import bpy
import random
def createRandomMat(object):
    newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
    object.data.materials.append(newMat)
    #newMat.use_nodes = False
    
    sel_objs = [objfor obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj.type == 'MESH']
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
    for obj in sel_objs:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        object = bpy.context.active_object
        createRandomMat(object)
        bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), 1)
```

Comment: You’re referring to the software 3DS Max and not the handheld Nintendo console, right?

Comment: Yes, The 3DS export feature was removed in 2.8 but is back in 4.0 alpha and in runs fine in 3.5.

Comment: Does 3DS Max have a node-based shading system?